# SQL Transaction Data: From basket line level data, identify number of baskets where a product appears as the only product in the basket

Tags: sql, sql-server

My transaction data has many columns but is generally structured as:

```
Basket_ID Product_ID  
basket1 product1  
basket1 product2  
basket1 product3  

basket2 product1  
basket2 product1
```

Each basket has many lines, with the basket_ID acting as the key.  Each instance of a product has it's own line in the basket, so two of the same item will still be over two lines.  The basket data also contains payment types, promotion details etc but this is eliminated by filtering sales_quantity = 1.

By product ID, I'd like to get to the total count of baskets where a product is the only item in the basket, and to also have the % of times where that product is bought as the only item in the basket.  I.e., product1 sells 100 times in all baskets, it was the only item in 5 baskets, therefore 5%.

I have some code that seems to correctly return the count, but I'm struggling with the % part.  It's also rather sub-optimal, so I'm sure there must be a more efficient way.

This seems to work (but is very messy) to return count of baskets grouped by product_id where the product is the only item in the basket:

```
drop table if exists #tempbasket

   --unique products basket size distribution
  select report_transaction_ID
  ,count(product_id) as uniq_prods
  into 
#tempbasket
  from 
    (
  select
  report_transaction_ID
  ,product_id
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRANSACTION_DATE) BETWEEN '2019-02-04' and '2019-04-04' 
  AND basket_id is not null 
  and PRODUCT_ID is not null
  AND sales_quantity = 1) q1
  group by REPORT_TRANSACTION_ID
  having count(PRODUCT_ID) = 1

  select
  product_id
  ,count(q1.report_transaction_ID) as num_single_item_baskets
  FROM 
  (
  select
  report_transaction_ID
  ,product_id
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRANSACTION_DATE) BETWEEN '2019-02-04' and '2019-04-04' 
  AND basket_id is not null 
  and PRODUCT_ID is not null
  AND sales_quantity = 1) q1
    inner join #tempbasket t2 on q1.REPORT_TRANSACTION_ID = t2.REPORT_TRANSACTION_ID 
    where uniq_prods = 1
  group by product_id
  order by count(q1.report_transaction_ID) desc
```

Then my even messier attempt at solving the %...:

```
 select
  q1.product_id
  ,count(q1.report_transaction_ID) as num_single_item_baskets
  ,count(q2.report_transaction_ID) as total_baskets
  ,(count(q1.report_transaction_ID)*1.00)/(count(q2.report_transaction_ID)*1.00) as pct_single_item_baskets
  FROM 
  (
  select
  report_transaction_ID
  ,product_id
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRANSACTION_DATE) BETWEEN '2019-02-04' and '2019-02-04' 
  AND basket_id is not null 
  and PRODUCT_ID is not null
  AND sales_quantity = 1) q1
    inner join #tempbasket t2 on q1.REPORT_TRANSACTION_ID = t2.REPORT_TRANSACTION_ID 
    inner join
    (
  select
  report_transaction_ID
  ,product_id
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE CONVERT(DATE, TRANSACTION_DATE) BETWEEN '2019-02-04' and '2019-02-04' 
  AND basket_id is not null 
  and PRODUCT_ID is not null
  AND sales_quantity = 1) q2 on q1.PRODUCT_ID = q2.product_id
  group by q1.product_id
  order by count(q1.report_transaction_ID) desc
```

Still running the second query after c30 mins, so unsure what that will return.  The first query runs but takes a while, the results seem relatively as expected though.

Any help appreciated, I'm convinced there's a better way than this!

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are asking . . . the question seems too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can use two levels of aggregation to answer your main question:

```
select count(*)
from (select Basket_ID 
      from transactions
      group by Bascket_ID
      having min(Product_ID) = max(Product_ID)
     ) b
```